# How to make new data available in the BigQuery public datasets marketplace?

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset

Some publicly available data added to personal projects can be generally useful.

Google BigQuery's documentation mentions

- [how to share a dataset with the public](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data#share_a_dataset_with_the_public)
- [how to grant access to a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#grant_access_to_a_dataset)

> This form of sharing seems, however, to depend on sending the link singly, is this so?

How can we make a dataset available on the [marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?filter=category:database), adding information related to it, as seen for

- [Chicago Taxi Trips](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/city-of-chicago-public-data/chicago-taxi-trips)
- [NYC TLC Trips](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/city-of-new-york/nyc-tlc-trips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this article on [offering a dataset to marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/datasets), Here are Technical requirements for you to attempt submit a dataset:

> **Technical requirements**
>
> - You must sign up to become a Google Cloud partner. Learn about the requirements to become a partner.
> - Your Google Cloud project name. If you haven't already done so, create a project.
> - We recommend YOUR_ORGANIZATION-public as your projectID.
> - Complete the project info form that the Cloud Marketplace team sends you.
> - You must have a logo or icon for the Cloud Marketplace listing, in the PNG format. The background of the logo must be transparent, and
>   not contain any text within it.

Aside from this there is also resource requirements, For more details about this please visit the article linked above.